# Avoid unique conflicts on insert SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, database-performance

I'm trying to insert into a table that has unique constraint on (ProductType, ProductOwnerid) in a way that when that key already exists that the contraint violation would not be triggered. So I have this SQL that works as intended:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductType, ProductOwnerId)
SELECT TOP 1 22, 44  FROM dbo.products prods
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT prods2.ProductType FROM dbo.products prods2 
    WHERE prods2.ProductType = 22 AND prods2.ProductOwnerId = 44)
```

Is this decent SQL or how could I improve this? I'm not a big fan of the TOP 1, how can I make this more readable/better performing?

Comment: Are 22 and 44 for demo only or are these two always in your query? Otherwise this doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Why do you want a constraint that will never fire. Remove it then.

Comment: Use a MERGE instead.

Comment: you could also go for `If select count ... = 0 Then Insert...`. that would at least make it better readable.

Comment: 22 and 44 are for demo purposes only, using parametarized queries/commands in production

Comment: Use of TOP 1 limits you to the very first row of the table. So this insert will never happen.,

Comment: 22 and 44 are selected if the row does not exist. If there exists at least one row then nothing is selected. This is logically correct, although the negation increases complexity, thats part of the reason why I'm wondering if there is an easier way to express this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MERGE statement is the SQL standard way to handle such cases.

> A relational database management system uses SQL MERGE (also called
>   upsert) statements to INSERT new records or UPDATE existing records
>   depending on whether or not a condition matches. It was officially
>   introduced in the SQL:2003 standard, and expanded in the SQL:2008
>   standard.

It is a little bit more verbose than your solution but I find it more readable. Also, the intention of the code is very clear since the MERGE statement is specialized in dealing with this exact scenario.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    ProductId INT IDENTITY(1, 1), 
    ProductType int, ProductOwnerId INT, 

    CONSTRAINT [unq_type_owner] UNIQUE (ProductType, ProductOwnerId)
);

MERGE INTO dbo.products p
USING (VALUES (22, 44))  AS source(ProductType, ProductOwnerId)
ON p.ProductType = source.ProductType AND p.ProductOwnerId = source.ProductOwnerId

WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT (ProductType, ProductOwnerId)
    VALUES (source.ProductType, source.ProductOwnerId)

-- OPTIONAL OUTPUT
OUTPUT $action, Inserted.* ;
```

Answer (score 0):

In this query, distinct will also work in place of top 1

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Products (ProductType, ProductOwnerId)
    SELECT DISTINCT 22, 44  
    FROM dbo.products prods
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT prods2.ProductType 
                      FROM dbo.products prods2 
                      WHERE prods2.ProductType = 22 AND prods2.ProductOwnerId = 44)
```